# distance() function accuracy for geopoints in GAE search API

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anyone have any experience or know of any documentation regarding the accuracy of the distance() function for geopoints in GAE search API?

I have 2 lat / long geo points, 47 meters apart. The distance is a fact as I have measured it. Google maps also confirms that to this accuracy.

However when I use the distance() function in a search API context, with first point being the origin, the second point is already retuned by the search at 26 meters (< 26 meters). I would expect < 47 or < 48.

Maybe the short distance is an issue. However, I would expect 1, 2 maybe 5 meters error margin, not 20. If it is the case, then not very practical for "query all restaurants within a radius of 50 or 100 meters"

Answer (score 0):

A few things to investigate:

- how accurate are the coordinates you are passing to distance()?
- what is generating the points you are passing to distance()?
- are you truncating the points to some lower precision?

One arc-second of latitude is about 31 meters, so if you want ± 5 meters accuracy, because errors accumulate, then each input needs to be ± 3.5 meters of its actual location, or ± 0.1 arc-seconds of accuracy. In decimal, this is ± 0.00003 degrees.

If you're using GPS to supply the coordinates, this is within its capability, but not reliably. It can guarantee ± 4 meters accuracy 95% of the time, so the best you might expect is ± 6 meters accuracy for distance.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response @Rong. The coordinates are of accuracy 9 digits right of the decimal point. They are returned for a supplied address to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/ (not using a GPS device). No truncation done. However, even if the coordinates are wrong, still the exact same coordinates are used as input for distance calculation using 1) google maps 2) Harvesine formula 3) measuring in the field 4) distance() function. Methods 1), 2) and 3) result in 47 meters, while method 4) returns as if distance is 26 meters. Any hints?

Comment: The magnitude of the error is similar to what one might expect if floats and doubles were being mixed. Are `latitude` and `longitude` of type `double`? If you're using `float` anywhere in the code, you get only 7 decimal digits precision and it won't give you any warning if you do something like `latitude = 42.562377606` (internally it will truncate `latitude` to 42.56238). Also, try this: `geopoint = search.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)` then compare `geopoint.getLatitude()` and `latitude` as well as `geopoint.getLongitude()` and `longitude`. Also, `geopoint.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing your testing in the development environment?  Supposedly the distance() function isn't available in the development environment:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/devserver

Maybe its available, but not reliable.